# Wordpress sub-directory Xampp installation doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, subdirectory

I would like to install the same Wordpress site, but in a sub-directory using Xampp, so in localhost.

What i try to do:

localhost/main_site/ **(as the main installation in htdocs of xampp, and it works fine)**

localhost/main_site/second_site **(for the second installation (the clone of the main installation), i create the sub-directory called "second_site", inside the main wordpress folder "main_site")**

the database is the same for the both site.

But what I tried to do didn't work, what can I do?

thanks in advance for the reply!

Comment: What error do you get in the log file?

Comment: shouldn't you modify the URL's stored in siteurl and home rows of the options table?